# Android and View size

Tags: android, android-layout

I would just like to know if every time I need to set the View's size (width or/and height) as a function of its parent size (e.g. width = 0.5 * parent_size), I have to create a custom View and override [onMeasure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)) or is there a way to do it using XML?
Thank you in advance!

Edit:

What I'd like to achieve is something like : place a view left aligned, with a width equals to 1/10th of the parent width and a height equals to 1/5th of the parent height. So on for other Views.

Comment: you can use LinearLayout as a container and android:layout weight attribute for example. You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight
But I think you don't need to use functions of parent size. Explain what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Demand LinearLayout uses the weight attribute to fill remaining space, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Use a Horizontal LinearLayout inside a Vertical LinearLayout. Or vice versa.... Too many of those will impact performance though ...

Comment: @ElDuderino that's not gonna work if there is only one View per Vertical/Horizontal LinearLayout, for the weight attribute to work there have to be at least two Views.

Comment: @user2302585 So, if you want to add only one element, you can add your view with weight=1 and one <Space> element with weight=9. But if you want to add 10 view in one row (1/10 of height for each) - you can use GridView for that or TableLayout.

Comment: @Demand Ok it looks like the Space element is what I was looking for, thank you very much! if you write that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use LinearLayout as a container and android:layout weight attribute for example. You can read more here: developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

So, if you want to add only one element, you can add your view with weight=1 and one  element with weight=9. But if you want to add 10 view in one row (1/10 of height for each) - you can use GridView for that or TableLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer with two nested LinearLayouts and a TextView in the upper left corner, the TextView is 10% of width and 10% of height.
Just to prove it works with only one view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         />

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to create a custom View and override `onMeasure()` or is there a
>   way to do it using XML?

There are no such way to achieve you goal using XML Layout file.

You have to manage this view dynamically .Your second approach is right approach .
You need to create dynamic view and make `onMeasure()` method according to your functions.

Comment: That's wrong, as Demand says in his comment you can use LinearLayout.